# Spring:mvc 4.0 nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
 <Jul 22, 2015 7:00:00 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet:
 "dispatcher" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "test".
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 31 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/classes/dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception
>   is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with element 'bean'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":mapping}' is expected.

I am receiving above exception while starting my Application, Please find my spring configurations below.

```
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

        xsi:schemaLocation="   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  

           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd   

             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   

               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">


        <mvc:interceptors>

                    <mvc:interceptor>

                                <bean name="cachingHeadersInterceptor" class="com.testcompany.test.interceptors.CacheInterceptor"/>

                    </mvc:interceptor>

        </mvc:interceptors>
```

Where as my app is working fine when I have replaced the interceptors like below

```
      <mvc:interceptors>

                                <bean name="cachingHeadersInterceptor" class="com.testcompany.test.interceptors.CacheInterceptor"/>

        </mvc:interceptors>
```

Help me correcting my configuration.

Comment: The exception is telling you what to do. You need to add a `<mvc:mapping />` before the `<bean />` element to the `<mvc:interceptor />` tag.

Comment: thanks M.Deinum it works...